# Liquidsoap Load Track Returned by Python Script

Tags: python, liquidsoap

I have a python script that makes a database call to get a music track. The script returns the path of that music file. How can I get Liquidsoap to call the python script and load the music file that the script returns?

I also need to know date/time when Liquidsoap plays that file and return that to the python script.

In liquidsoap, I currently just have it watch for changes to a playlist file:

```
myplaylist = playlist(mode="normal",reload=0,reload_mode="watch","/home/wruser/radio/test.m3u")
```

The python script makes the database call and then writes the test.m3u file.

I am thinking that perhaps there is a way in Liquidsoap to just call the script and have it return the location of the file so Liquidsoap can then load it. I would also want to know the date/time Liquidsoap does this so I can have python script save that info back to database.

I am using liquidsoap to send output to Icecast server.

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: Please tell what you have tried. Show some code.

Comment: If you want to play music with a python script, you can use some library like playsound. Python also has librosa for all sound processing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer to getting results back from python script by using this code:

```
def my_request_function() = 
  # Get the first line of my external process
  result = list.hd(default="", get_process_lines("python3 /home/wruser/radio/python/test.py"))
  print(result)
  # Create and return a request using this result
  [request.create(result)]
end

# Create the source
s = request.dynamic.list(my_request_function)
```

Comment: You can share your code?